# Custom mobile validator using spring boot

Tags: java, matcher

Hi Guys I am trying to create a custom mobile validator. But each time whether the regex is true or not it is returning false. Can you help me with that

```java
public class MobileValidator implements ConstraintValidator<MobileValidation, String> {


    public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("^[6-9]\\d{9}$");
        Matcher match = regex.matcher(value);
        if(value != null && !value.equals(match.matches())){
            System.out.println(context);
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Why should value match `match.matches`? The latter returns a `boolean` a `String` is never equal to a `boolean`. What you probably meant to write is `value != null && match.matches()`.

Comment: It is not about regex here, but about the use of `Matcher` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
    Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("^[6-9]\\d{9}$");
    Matcher match = regex.matcher(value);
    if (StringUtil.isNotBlank(value) && match.matches()) {
        System.out.println(context);
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`match.matches()` returns a boolean that says whether the pattern matched or not; you don't need to compare it with the result, you should just use the boolean:

```java
public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
    Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("^[6-9]\\d{9}$");
    Matcher match = regex.matcher(value);
    if (match.matches()) {
        System.out.println(context);
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Function Pattern.matcher not return value string, please use:

public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[6-9]\d{9}$");

return null != value && pattern.matcher(value).matches();
}